# Total differential of function with arguments multiplied by a scalar

Tags: derivatives, differential, chain-rule

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, in a proof, that I have just read, the following equality was used:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(tx)=\sum x_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx).$$

However, using the chain rule I get the following:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(tx)=\sum x_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial (tx_i)}(tx).$$
I subsituted $u(x):=tx$, wrote $f(tx)=f\circ u(x)$ and used the chain rule to obtain this. I do not understand how you would get the first equation. Can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as 
$${\partial f\over \partial(tx_i)}\ ,$$
but there is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its first variable, evaluated at $tx$:
$$f_{.1}(tx)={\partial f\over\partial x_1}(tx)\ .$$
This, together with the chain rule, leads to the correct first formula in your question.